# Interact with console program via batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to start a console program via batch script. Starting the console program works fine. I am starting it via `call xxx.exe para para`. The problem is that the console program wants an input like that after it is started.

```
call xxx.exe para para
please type in password:_
```

Is it possible to make the input of the password from the batch script.

Comment: is that windows batch? Otherwise what is `call`?

Comment: It is tagged with bash ... so it should be /bin/bash? But indeed, the command call does not exist. And ... the program he is calling is a .exe file. Seems not to be bash.

Comment: yes it's windows bash. 
its CALL xxx.exe it works

Comment: but how can I pipe from the bash script into my exe programm?

Comment: nice to know the new member of "bash" family.. windows bash.. I would edit your question, with right tags, so that you could get right answers.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are using *batch* or *bash*, as it seemed originally, you could try this simple piping:

```
echo YourPassword| program.exe parameters...
```

Note that if it is indeed a batch script, it is vital to make sure there's no extra space between your password and the `|`, or it will be passed along with the password, *as part of the password*. In bash, if I'm not much mistaken, such a space would be disregarded (or maybe it would only be so if you enclosed the echoed string in quotation marks, I'm not entirely sure).

Anyway, the above doesn't always work, as some programs implement password reading in a way that disregards the input stream piped from another command.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question "Windows" and "Batch" and asked about "batch" in the question. The answer to that question is: Yes, use `set` like this:

```
set /p password=please type in password:
```

If you're really asking about 'bash' shell, you should re-tag your question (and change the text).